# Error while importing data into R because of wrong number format

Tags: r, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to import data into R from a data file, which I created with Mathematica.
I am using the scan function in the following way

scan(file="mydata.dat",sep=",")

and get the error

Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got '4.451420174737787*^-6'

Now I figuerd the problem is the number format in my data file. But I have no idea what to do. How can I import my data?

Comment: Substitute `*^` with `e` prior to, during (e.g., using sed), or after import (import as character).

Comment: @ Roland: Thank you very much! I used sed to replace *^ with e and it did work.

Comment: If you like you might request the maintainer of `foreign` to add Mathematica file I/O .  May not be worth the effort :-)

Comment: For portability saving data from mathematica you should use `Export` to some common format suce as `.csv` instead of teaching other programs to read the native mathematica fomat.

Comment: @george: I tried this too, but I still had the *^ in the data.

Comment: i think you are doing something odd, saving inputform of values somehow. show the mathematica code if you want to sort that out.

Comment: Are you aware of [RLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/RLink/guide/RLink.html)?  It will allow you to transfer the data to R directly and save it in an R-compatible format within R.